# SwiftUI Modal Inherits SearchBar during Sheet Presentation

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Consider the following example with a list and a button wrapped in a `HStack` that opens up a sheet:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var showSheet = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    button
                }
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .searchable(text: $text)
        }
    }

    var button: some View {
        Button("Press", action: { showSheet = true })
            .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
                modalView
            }
    }

    var modalView: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

On press of the button, a modal is presented to the user. However, the searchable modifier gets passed to the modal, see this [video](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T2YYi.gif).

Now if the `HStack` is removed, everything works fine:

```
List {
    button
    Text("Hello World")
}
```

In addition, everything works also fine if the modal is not a `NavigationView`:

```
var modalView: some View {
    List {
        Text("Test")
    }
}
```

Does somebody know what the problem here might be or is it once again one of those weird SwiftUI bugs?

Answer (score 0):

putting the `sheet`, outside of the button and the List, works for me. I think `.sheet` is not meant to be inside a List, especially  where `searchable` is operating.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var text: String = ""
    @State var showSheet = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                HStack {
                    button
                }
                Text("Hello World")
            }
            .searchable(text: $text)
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            modalView
        }
    }
    
    var button: some View {
        Button("Press", action: { showSheet = true })
    }
    
    var modalView: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                Text("Test")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in my question, I noticed that this works too. However, the idea was to have the button as a separated component (in a separate view) that opens the sheet. But to be honest, I only see this as the only possible option. Let's hope for SwiftUI 4.0.

Comment: I didn't see you mentioning putting the `.sheet` outside the List worked. Let's wait for SwiftUI 4.0.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Putting it outside the button (also outside `HStack`) does the same: It works. Sorry for the confusion. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Another workaround is to use navigationBarHidden = true, but then you must live without the navigation bar in the sheet view.

```
var modalView: some View {
    NavigationView {
        List {
            Text("Test")
        }
        .navigationBarHidden(true)
    }
}
```

Btw, on iPadOS it helps to use .searchable(text: $text, placement: .sidebar)